# How to force Dojo TitlePane to overlap with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fugKS/) which has two `TitlePane` widgets in the top right of the center pane.  Right now, when the right `TitlePane` ("Switch Basemap") is clicked, it causes the left `TitlePane` ("Map Overlays") to shift to the left.  Instead, I would like for the right `TitlePane`, when opened, to hide the left `TitlePane` rather than shift it.

I have tried playing with `z-index`, `overflow`, `position`, and `float`, but no luck so far.  I am fairly new to Dojo so I think I haven't found the correct combination of style parameters.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your titlepanes an id, and then add the evenhooks as shown below. To give a widget an id, simply put it into the *props* as `id:'leftId'`. I will use the classNames of yours as id in example.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var wLeft = dijit.byId('leftTitlePane');
    var wRight = dijit.byId('rightTitlePane');
    dojo.connect(wLeft, 'onShow', function() {
        wRight.domNode.style.display = 'none';
    });
    dojo.connect(wLeft, 'onHide', function() {
        // wait a few for collapse to finish
        setTimeout(function() {wRight.domNode.style.display = '';}, 120);
    });
    dojo.connect(wRight, 'onShow', function() {
        wLeft.domNode.style.display = 'none';
    });
    dojo.connect(wRight, 'onHide', function() {
        // wait a few for collapse to finish
        setTimeout(function() {wLeft.domNode.style.display = '';}, 120);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works beautifully!  Thank you.  :)